# How to access data in variable object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to access data in my variable object:

```
foo = {
    tweet1 : [{
        user: {
            profile_image_url : "assets/avatar.png",
            name : "@Hodor"
        },
        text : "Hodor Hodor Hodor Hodor Hodor Hodor Hodor..... Hodor"
    }],
    tweet2 : [{
        user: {
            profile_image_url : "assets/avatar.png",
            name : "@johnsnow"
        },
        text : "Someone once said that I know nothing..."
    }],
    tweet3 : [{
        user: {
            profile_image_url : "assets/avatar.png",
            name : "@drwho"
        },
        text : "Fantastic!"
    }]
};
```

And I have my loop set up which gives me 3 objects:

```
for (var i in foo) {
    console.log( foo[ i ] );
}
```

However I am unsure how to access the data further and grab the text and user keys for each object. Thoughts?

Comment: FYI, that's a pretty poor data structure. If `foo` just contains a bunch of tweets, it should be an array, not an object. At which point you can access the tweet objects by index. It's also unusual that each tweet is a single element array, shouldn't it just be an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep iterating as deep as you want to go:

```
for (var key in foo) {
    for (var i = 0; i < foo[key].length; i++) {
        //Iterating each array of each object

        //Keys of each array
        for (var anotherKey in foo[key][i]) {
            console.log(foo[key][i][anotherKey]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, worked like a charm. I thought I had to use another loop inside the loop, makes perfect sense. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you simply have to refer to the nested object first. e.g.

```
 console.log(foo.tweet1[0]);
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick...

```
for (var i in foo)
{
    console.log(foo[i][0].user);
}
```